# How to Installing Sysmon with Config file on Remote Machine

Tags: powershell, shell, remote-access, remoting

**Task I'm trying to accomplish**

a program that **copies Sysmon to remote machines** and **installs it with a given configuration** file that catches all the events listed in the specifications.

**I am able to copy all the files successfully.** But when I try to **run installer sysmon64.exe at a remote machine**, it gives me an error.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Sysmon.ps1

**Error:**

```
System Monitor v12.0 - System activity monitor
Copyright (C) 2014-2020 Mark Russinovich and Thomas Garnier
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : 192.168.0.5
 

Usage:
Install:                 c:\windows\cpsysmon\Sysmon64.exe -i [<configfile>]
Update configuration:    c:\windows\cpsysmon\Sysmon64.exe -c [<configfile>]
Install event manifest:  c:\windows\cpsysmon\Sysmon64.exe -m
Print schema:            c:\windows\cpsysmon\Sysmon64.exe -s
Uninstall:               c:\windows\cpsysmon\Sysmon64.exe -u [force]
  -c   Update configuration of an installed Sysmon driver or dump the
       current configuration if no other argument is provided. Optionally
       take a configuration file.
  -i   Install service and driver. Optionally take a configuration file.
  -m   Install the event manifest (done on service install as well).
  -s   Print configuration schema definition of the specified version.
       Specify 'all' to dump all schema versions (default is latest).
  -u   Uninstall service and driver. Adding force causes uninstall to proceed
       even when some components are not installed.

The service logs events immediately and the driver installs as a boot-start driver to capture activity from early in the boot that the service will write to the event 
log when it starts.
On Vista and higher, events are stored in "Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Sysmon/Operational". On older systems, events are written to the System 
event log.
Use the '-? config' command for configuration file documentation.More examples are available on the Sysinternals website.
Specify -accepteula to automatically accept the EULA on installation, otherwise you will be interactively prompted to accept it.
Neither install nor uninstall requires a reboot.
```

**Script**

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.5 -Credential "Study\Administrator"

Copy-Item "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Sysmon\*.*" -ToSession $Session -Destination C:\Windows\cpsysmon\  -Recurse

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {cmd.exe /C "c:\windows\cpsysmon\Sysmon64.exe" /silent -Wait}
```

Comment: Sorry! 

I am trying to install the Sysmon on a remote machine which is part of the domain. 

I am able to copy but not able to run the installer which i copied successfully.

Comment: I think the error it's "RemoteException"

Comment: @KenWhite Updated the post for clarity! Thankyou!

Comment: Every time I try to run the installer, where I copied it. It gives me the above error. Strangely it displays the SYSMON usage information but doesn't run the sysmon64.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need replace

```
cmd.exe /C "c:\windows\cpsysmon\Sysmon64.exe" /silent -Wait
```

by

```
cmd.exe /C "c:\windows\cpsysmon\Sysmon64.exe" -i -n -accepteula
```